Storing Other Data in IdentityDb Context
I am using EF Core and Identity library in my .net Core project, so I have to create separate context for both my entities (products etc.) and Identity, but I cannot create a relationship for separate contexts.When I collect all the data in a single context (IdentityDb Context), I can create a relationship and access it.
namespace Auction_DataAccess.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PaymentHistory> PaymentHistories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Bid>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
            builder.Entity<PaymentHistory>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
            builder.Entity<Vehicle>().HasKey(b => b.Id);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(e => e.ToTable(name: "Users"));

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.Name });
        }
    }
}

Is it safe to keep identity(user etc) and other data(product etc) together in IdentityDb Context?


Is it safe to keep identity(user etc) and other data(product etc)
together in IdentityDb Context?

Yes, it is generally safe to keep your Identity data and other business-related data in the same IdentityDbContext.
As far as I known, there are some benefits, such as:

You can easily define relationships between your business entities and your Identity data within the same context, which can simplify your database structure and codebase.

Only have one DbContext to manage, which reduces complexity. All migrations, database interactions, and transaction management are handled through a single context.


For the separate DbContext, for most of the time I don't suggest using it. But if one day you might decide and go with a 3rd party auth provider and forget about managing identity yourself. At which point I think it is benefit, you may do some migration, throw away the identity database as it is no longer needed.
